# Mysql OneToMany JOIN most recent record only

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, groupwise-maximum

I have two tables `customers` and their `contacts`. A customer can have many contact details. In a case i need to get only the last added contact details for the customers.I can attain this by `subquery`. But when the data is huge, I'm facing performace lack on querying all the customers data.

> Customer table (customers_customers)

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_name      | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| logo              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

> Contacts table (customers_customercontacts)

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've tried with the folowing queries, I'm getting results, but query is slow.

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.company_name,
    d.mobile
FROM customers_customers AS c
LEFT JOIN customers_customercontacts AS d
    ON d.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM customers_customercontacts WHERE d.customer_id = d.id);
```

and

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.company_name,
    d.mobile
FROM customers_customers AS c
LEFT JOIN customers_customercontacts AS d
    ON d.id = (SELECT id FROM customers_customercontacts WHERE d.customer_id = d.id
               ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

I need get get the customer's company_names and the last added phone_number of the each company_names.
Is there any optimized way or a way without using subquery, to attain this?

> **Solved**

NonCorrelated Subqueries always given better performance over than Correlated Subqueries.

Comment: can you [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) your query?

Comment: I need to get customer company names and their phone numbers. Only one phone number for the each customers and that should be the last added one.

Comment: Answer by **Bill Karwin** might help you [`Retrieving the last record in each group`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/853360)

Comment: @Rajez no i mean use the explain syntax, the table might not be optimized and there should be an index somewhere

Comment: Optimal [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second join to a subquery which identifies the most recent contact record for each customer:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.company_name,
    d1.mobile
FROM customers_customers AS c
LEFT JOIN customers_customercontacts AS d1
    ON c.id = d1.customer_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM customers_customercontacts
    GROUP BY customer_id
) AS d2
    ON d1.customer_id = d2.customer_id AND
       d1.id = d2.max_id;
```

This is a modification of your first query attempt.  Note that your join condition was broken, because it does not really relate the customer and contacts table properly.  The basic join should be `customers_customers.id` matches to `customers_customercontacts.customer_id`.  On top of this correction, I do an additional join to restrict to the most recent contact record for each customer.

One reason this approach may improve performance over what you had originally is that this query uses a non correlated subquery to find the most recent contact for each customer.  Your original attempts used correlated subqueries which tend to not perform well.

Comment: Thank you. I'm seeing good improvement in query duration. Can you explain how this change improves the performance ?

Comment: @Rajez I added an explanation.